# How to get the smallest numberA that is N times another numberB, and bigger or equal numberC

Tags: floating-point, precision

I want to get the smallest number (floatA) that is N times a number(floatB), and this number must be bigger or equal to another number (floatC), for example

```
float_c = 20.0
float_b = 7.0
than number that is N times float_b is: 21, 28, 35 ...
so float_a is 21.0
```

some code like below might not work (I am not sure)

```
let tmp = float_c / float_b;
let tmp = tmp.ceil();
float_a = tmp * float_b;

/*
e.g: 
float_c = 21.0
float_b = 7.0;
let tmp = 21.0 /7.0;  // 3.00000000000001;
let tmp = tmp.ceil();   // 4.0
float_a = tmp * 7.0; //28, that's worng
*/
```

Will this code below work?

```
float_c = 21.0
float_b = 7.0;
let tmp = 21.0 / 7.0; // 3.00000000001
let tmp2 = tmp.ceil(); // 4.0
let float_a = tmp2 * float_b;
let float_backtest = float_a - float_b;

if (float_backtest - float_c).abs() < epsilon:
    return float_c
else:
    return float_a;
```

Comment: You are looking for the smallest integer `N`, such that for given `b`, `c`: `n * b >= c`? Do you need to handle any border cases (infinities/NaNs/zeros, negative `b` or `c`)? What about cases where `N` is not exactly representable as a float?

Comment: Assuming finite, positive `b`, `c`, and you don't need to know `N`, I think `a = c+(b-fmod(c,b))` should work (assuming you have a working `fmod`) -- but technically that could result in an `a` which is not exactly representable (i.e. after rounding it would not be an integer multiply of `b`).

Comment: @chtz: If `c` is a multiple of `b`, `c+(b-fmod(c,b))` produces the next higher multiple, but `c` is the desired result. Also, if `c` is less than `b`, it may have lower bits, so `b - fmod(c, b)` may be inexact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c` and `b` are positive, then this C code produces the least multiple of `b` that is greater than `c`:

```
// If c <= b, b is the first multiple of b greater than or equal to c.
if (c <= b)
    a = b;
else
{
    // Get the remainder of c modulo b.  This is exact by nature of fmod.
    double r = fmod(c, b);

    // If c is exactly a multiple of b, it is the desired result.
    if (r == 0)
        a = c;

    /* Otherwise, calculate the amount to add to c to make it a multiple,
       then add it. "b - r" is exact because r cannot have any bits lower
       in position value than b has (because b <= c) nor any higher
       (because r < b). The addition of c may be inexact, but then the
       desired result is not representable.
    */
    else
        a = b - r + c;
}
```

Comment: I do not assert this is optimal; this is just an initial answer. Would be nice to have criteria added to the question, such as whether `b` and `c` are known to be positive.

Comment: Suggest `if (c < b)` --> `if (b >= c)`  for "... this number must be bigger or equal to another number (floatC)".  Current code fails when `b == 0`.  (`b==0` is a problem when the `if` fails, even with this change.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Re “Current code fails when `b == 0`”: The answer starts “If `c` and `b` are positive…”

Comment: Fair point, yet `b >= c` matches the comment better.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I avoid `>` and `>=` so that all comparisons have the lesser (if true) number on the left. That consistency helps clarify complicated code, more so, I find, than matching it to wording.